# Elasticsearch query to search two word combination with space

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have a elasticsearch query to search the data based on name.

My query is

```
$http.post(elasticSearchURL,{ "filter": { "and": [{ "term": { "Name": "allan" } } ] } })
```

The above query works fine for single word search but when I give two words with space it doesn't picks any data for it.

My query is not working for below scenario.

```
{ "filter": { "and": [{ "term": { "Name": "allan edward" } } ] } }
```

I dont know what keyword should I have to append to satisfy my search scenario.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how is the field that you are querying analyzed? With the `standard analyzer`? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Phrase match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html) is what you are looking for.

A query like below should work fine -

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "title": "allan edward"
        }
    }
}
```